# Simple Javascript Validation not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do the following:

HTML Code

```
<body>
    <form name="myform">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="first_name"></td>
            <td><p id="demo"></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" id="Submit" onclick="validate()"></td>
        </tr>
    </form></body>
```

JavaScript Code

```
<script>
    function validate(){

        var fname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
        if(fname.length>0){
            document.getElementById("demo").value="";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("demo").value="Name field empty";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

when I click the button with the empty First name field it should assign "name field empty" but it does not do that even though the control of the script goes there but it does not print anything in the <p> tag.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)**

Answer (score -3, accepted):

While I agree there is a better place to ask this question, that still doesn't mean you shouldn't get an answer.

To explain your problem, your trying to set the value of an HTML tag, but it isn't the value that you need to set.  You need to target the inner HTML of that element instead.

try this

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Name field empty";
```

Also here is a reference to some [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601